# Novel in which an alien federation initially opposes humanity's advance towards interstellar space, then hires them to help them fight a war

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens, space

Humanity in the not too distant future has successfully colonized its solar system, and is now on verge of developing faster-than-light drives. A peaceful alien federation spanning the galaxy and monitoring human progress concludes that humanity is too aggressive and militarily violent to become a space faring society, hence they decide to cordon them off.

When an extragalactic alien menace threatens their galaxy, the federation or group, though technologically advanced, lacks the military expertise or strategic mindset to fight adequately. As a result, in exchange for a minor contribution of technologies, they hire the humans as mercenaries to fight the war for them and train peaceful aliens as armies.

Comment: In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: Alan Dean Foster's "With Friends Like These" is another story on that theme but not the one you're looking for, as it's not a novel and doesn't match your description.

Comment: Was it just some local fight on a selected planet or some kind of intergalactic warfare?

Comment: [Star Guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Guard) is about that kind of the local fight on the selected planet.